# What is the equivalent of accessing a shared folder through windows run, given an IP in linux?

Tags: shared-folders

I have been given an IP of a.b.c.d and told to access it by opening Windows run and typing `\\a.b.c.d\`

How do I access the same folder through Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, you should be able to open a Windows share using the Nautilus file manager, either by navigating to `Other locations` --> `Connect to server` and entering the URI `smb://a.b.c.d/`, or from a terminal as

```
nautilus smb://a.b.c.d/
```

You may be prompted for a password - if the share doesn't require one, then leave the box empty.

Nautilus uses the `gvfs` backend, which unlike the `mount` command doesn't require root privileges on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to mount it using `cifs`.

Assuming you have the correct package installed (`cifs-utils` on ubuntu and debian) you can run:

```
mount -t cifs //a.b.c.d/ /share
```

This will mount the share on the directory `/share`. If you need to authenticate, you may want to specify a user and potentially a domain:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,domain=domainname //a.b.c.d/ /share
```

Comment: I got this error - https://imgur.com/a/jmKlBAx

It asked for password. But no password was specified.

Comment: If there is no password required use the `-o guest` option.